# Istio AuthorizationPolicy with Wildcard

Tags: authorization, istio

Does authorizationpolicy not supports any wildcard pattern on paths?

I have the following endpoints:

```
/my-service/docs/active (GET)
/my-service/docs/<id>/activate/<bool> (PUT)
```

The  first one will get all active docs, and second will activate/deactivate the specific doc.
I’ve tried to set it on the authorizationpolicy and it seems to ignore this policy due to willdcard.

```yaml
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: my-service-private
  namespace: default
spec:
  action: DENY
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app:my-service
  rules:
    - from:
        - source:
            notNamespaces: [ "default" ]
      to:
        - operation:
            methods: ["GET"]
            paths: ["/my-service/docs/active"]
        - operation:
            methods: ["PUT"]
            paths: ["/my-service/docs/*/activate/*"]
```

any different  solution here except updating all my endpoints?

10x

Comment: What is your istio version? According to istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/#Rule), Authorization Policy does support wildcard, but I think  the issue is with the `*/activate/*` path, because paths can use wildcards only at the start, end or whole string. There is an issue on [github](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/25021) about that , it's still open so there is no answer for that, for now.

Comment: I'd change the endpoint to something like `/my-service/docs/activate/<id>/<bool>` . This way you should be able to use policies without issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments

According to istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/#Rule):

> ### Rule
>
> Rule matches requests from a list of sources that perform a list of
> operations subject to a list of conditions. A match occurs when at
> least one source, operation and condition matches the request. An
> empty rule is always matched.
>
> Any string field in the rule supports Exact, Prefix, Suffix and
> Presence match:
>
> - Exact match: “abc” will match on value “abc”.
> - Prefix match: “abc*” will match on value “abc” and “abcd”.
> - Suffix match: “*abc” will match on value “abc” and “xabc”.
> - Presence match: “*” will match when value is not empty.

So Authorization Policy does support wildcard, but I think the issue is with the `*/activate/*` path, because paths can use wildcards only at the start, end or whole string, double wildcard just doesn't work.

There are related open github issues about that:

- https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/16585
- https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/25021

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i saw, the open issues.
for now i've updated my paths to includs only single wildcard as this was the only working scenario as you've mentioned.

10x