# Istio authorization - Pattern matching in Istio 'paths' field

Tags: istio

I want to create a rule in the Istio authorization:

```
            - to:
                - operation:
                    methods: [ "POST" ]
                    paths: [ "/data/api/v1/departments/*/users/*/position" ]
              when:
                - key: request.auth.claims[resource_access][roles]
                  values: [ "edit" ]
```

so I want to use path variables here (in places with `'*'`). What should I put instead of `'*'` to make it working?
It doesn't work in the current setup.

I get 'RBAC denied', I have a role `'edit'` and path to that role is okay. It works fine for endpoints without `'*'` signs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this answer as a community wiki as similar question has been already answered here:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Answer: Istio authorization - Pattern matching in Istio 'paths' field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65791478/12257134)*

Part of the question:

> ```
>        - operation:
>            methods: ["PUT"]
>            paths: ["/my-service/docs/*/activate/*"]
> ```

Answer:

> According to istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/#Rule):
>
> > ### Rule
> >
> > Rule matches requests from a list of sources that perform a list of
> > operations subject to a list of conditions. A match occurs when at
> > least one source, operation and condition matches the request. An
> > empty rule is always matched.
> >
> > Any string field in the rule supports Exact, Prefix, Suffix and
> > Presence match:
> >
> > - Exact match: “abc” will match on value “abc”.
> > - Prefix match: “abc*” will match on value “abc” and “abcd”.
> > - Suffix match: “*abc” will match on value “abc” and “xabc”.
> > - Presence match: “*” will match when value is not empty.
>
> So Authorization Policy does support wildcard, but I think the issue is with the `*/activate/*` path, because paths can use wildcards only at the start, end or whole string, double wildcard just doesn't work.
>
> There are related open github issues about that:
>
> - https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/16585
> - https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/25021